# To run bitcoin core testnet on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, testnet, ubuntu

How can I run Bitcoin core testnet version on ubuntu 16.04 platform ? I am getting so many reference about how to run bitcoin core mainnet but it will take around 20 days to synchronize with the network as per my bandwidth and also will take my half of the HDD. So I opt for Testnet. Can someone explain me how to insatll bitcoin core testnet on Ubuntu 16.04? I would be grateful. Step by step explanation or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running ```bitcoind``` from the command line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After having installed Bitcoin core on your machine, run the following command to start synchronising the testnet blockchain

`bitcoind -testnet -daemon`

The synchronisation starts as a daemon and runs in the background, you can issue the following the command to see the progress

`tailf ~/.bitcoin/testnet3/debug.log`

To access the command line apis , just add the -testnet parameter

`bitcoin-cli -testnet getinfo`

Update: The RPC getinfo is deprecated, use getblockchaininfo for it to work with the latest version

`bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockchaininfo`

Answer (score 6):

getinfo is now deprecated. Use getblockchaininfo instead:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockchaininfo
```

I don't have 50 reputation to comment. Otherwise, I would've added this as a comment.

Comment: Upvoted, now you have 51 :)