# How to generate a testnet address?

Tags: testnet, address-generation, address-format

Bitcoin addresses can be generated on this site https://www.bitaddress.org, but the test network needs m or n at the beginning of the address, where can those be generated？

Comment: Use the testnet version. https://www.bitaddress.org/?testnet=true

Comment: Pokes @NickODell: [Please post answers as answers, not as comments!](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/633/5406) ;)

Comment: @Murch Character limits, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitaddress.org itself allows you to create Testnet addresses (hat tip to Nick ODell). The generator for testnet addresses can be found by appending `?testnet=true` to the URL. The site now appears to put the release version in the URL, so the link to generate a testnet address on bitaddress.org is https://www.bitaddress.org/bitaddress.org-v3.3.0-SHA256-dec17c07685e1870960903d8f58090475b25af946fe95a734f88408cef4aa194.html?testnet=true

Note that using an online website may be a convenient approach to generate a testnet address quickly. **Do not use online websites to generate mainnet addresses, especially not if you intend to transact significant sums.**

Alternatively, you could use a wallet that supports testnet, see e.g. [Running Bitcoin Core in testnet mode](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/54986/5406).

Comment: it doesn't work (anymore at least).address it prints is mainnet

Comment: Thanks, @АлексейНеудачин. I updated the URL to the new location of the testnet generator.

Answer (score 5):

Assume your hexadecimal private key (256 bits in length) is **0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff** for demonstrative purposes.

Use this [**table**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table) to specify interger version to use the Bitcoin Explorer ([**bx**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/Download-BX)) command to compute WIF private keys and addresses for numerous altcoins.

1. *Compute associated **Testnet** compressed WIF key:*

   `% echo 0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff | sed 's/$/01/' | bx base58check-encode -v 239`

   **`cMahgGtgBvsRn7SZFuFCuKGnV8H8yxYLegVcaRsLL2LjD6WFLuAg`**
2. *Compute associated **Testnet** compressed public address from **secp256k1** elliptic curve using the same private key:*

   `% echo 0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff | bx ec-to-public | bx ec-to-address -v 111`

   **`n47QBape2PcisN2mkHR2YnhqoBr56iPhJh`**

It is worth examining the result of this example:

`% echo cMahgGtgBvsRn7SZFuFCuKGnV8H8yxYLegVcaRsLL2LjD6WFLuAg | bx base58check-decode`

```
{
    checksum 3112764957
    payload 0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff01
    version 239
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my step by step tutorial from create a wallet to push or broadcast a transaction in test net:
[step-by-step-create-and-broadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction-on-testnet](https://medium.com/@athamidn/estep-by-step-create-and-broadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction-on-testnet-588daacc2b7a?source=friends_link&sk=2c9a310c02801d09c667608d4651e80f)